Playwright not using fresh fixtures for each test
I'm using playwright for our automation and we're debating should we switch to fixtures or no.
We need to access same variables from multiple pages/classes so we're using repository pattern for managing variables and we call it testContext.
import { User } from './variables/User'
import { Bank } from './variables/Bank'

export class TestContext {
  public user = User
  public bank = Bank
}

type Bank = {
  bankName: string | null
  routingNumber: number | null
  accountNumer: number | null
}

export const Bank: Bank = {
  bankName: null,
  routingNumber: null,
  accountNumer: null,
}


We use POM so the structure goes like this, base.ts > basePage.ts > all other pages
short example:

import { TestContext } from '../state/TestContext'
export class Base {
  readonly page: Page
  protected context: TestContext

  constructor(page: Page, context: TestContext) {
    this.page = page
    this.context = context
  }
}

import { Base } from './Base'
import { TestContext } from '../state/TestContext'
export class BasePage extends Base {
  readonly page: Page

  constructor(page: Page, context: TestContext) {
    super(page, context)
    this.page = page
    this.context = context
  }
}


import { BasePage } from './BasePage'
import { TestContext } from '../state/TestContext'
export class HomePage extends BasePage {
  readonly page: Page

  constructor(page: Page, context: TestContext) {
    super(page, context)
    this.page = page
    this.context = context
  }
}



Our test are working like this. We initialize objects in beforeEach and pass them page and testContext so that each test can only see variables for that test, e.g. test2 can't see variables from test1...
import { BrowserContext, Page, test } from '@playwright/test'
import { Base } from '../../pages/Base'
import { TestContext } from '../../state/TestContext'
import { LoginPage } from '../../pages/LoginPage'
import { RegisterPage } from '../../pages/RegisterPage'
import { NavigationPage } from '../../pages/NavigationPage'
import { HomePage } from '../../pages/HomePage'

let context: BrowserContext
let page: Page
let testContext: TestContext

let loginPage: LoginPage
let registerPage: RegisterPage
let navigationPage: NavigationPage
let homePage: HomePage

test.describe.configure({ mode: 'parallel' })

test.describe('Login Tests', () => {
  test.beforeAll('Before All', async () => {
    Base.initializeEnvironment()
  })

  test.beforeEach('Before Each', async ({ browser, request}, testInfo) => {
    console.log('\n' + `[TEST STARTED] - ${testInfo.title}` + '\n')
    context = await browser.newContext()
    page = await context.newPage()

    testContext = new TestContext()
    loginPage = new LoginPage(page, testContext)
    registerPage = new RegisterPage(page, testContext)
    navigationPage = new NavigationPage(page, testContext)
    homePage = new HomePage(page, testContext)

    await loginPage.launchRWA()
    await registerPage.generateAndRegisterUserAPI(request)
  })

  test.afterEach('After Each', async ({}, testInfo) => {
    console.log('\n' + `[TEST FINISHED] - with status [${testInfo.status}]` + '\n')
  })

  test('Login To RWA - New User - Positive Oboarding - UI', async ({ request }) => {
    await registerPage.goToRegisterPage()
    await registerPage.generateAndRegisterUserUI(request)
    await loginPage.loginNewUser()
    await loginPage.positiveOnboarding()
    await navigationPage.logout()
  })


Now we wanna have less code and wanna implement fixtures
import { test as base, expect, Page, BrowserContext } from '@playwright/test';
import { TestContext } from '../state/TestContext';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/LoginPage';
import { RegisterPage } from '../pages/RegisterPage';
import { NavigationPage } from '../pages/NavigationPage';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/HomePage';

type Fixtures = {
  context: BrowserContext;
  page: Page;
  testContext: TestContext;
  loginPage: LoginPage;
  registerPage: RegisterPage;
  navigationPage: NavigationPage;
  homePage: HomePage;
};

export const test = base.extend<Fixtures>({
  context: async ({ browser }, use) => {
    const context = await browser.newContext();
    await use(context);
    await context.close();
  },

  page: async ({ context }, use) => {
    const page = await context.newPage();
    await use(page);
  },

  testContext: async ({}, use) => {
    const testContext = new TestContext();
    await use(testContext);
  },

  loginPage: async ({ page, testContext }, use) => {
    await use(new LoginPage(page, testContext));
  },

  registerPage: async ({ page, testContext }, use) => {
    await use(new RegisterPage(page, testContext));
  },

  navigationPage: async ({ page, testContext }, use) => {
    await use(new NavigationPage(page, testContext));
  },

  homePage: async ({ page, testContext }, use) => {
    await use(new HomePage(page, testContext));
  },
});

export { expect };


and lets use some test file
import { test, expect } from '../base.ts';
import { Base } from '../../pages/Base';

test.describe.configure({ mode: 'serial' });

test.describe('Login Tests', () => {
  test.beforeAll(async () => {
    Base.initializeEnvironment();
  });

  test.beforeEach(async ({}, testInfo) => {
    console.log('\n' + `[TEST STARTED] - ${testInfo.title}` + '\n');
  });

  test.afterEach(async ({}, testInfo) => {
    console.log('\n' + `[TEST FINISHED] - with status [${testInfo.status}]` + '\n');
  });

  test('TEST 1', async ({request, registerPage, testContext}) => {
    await registerPage.generateAndRegisterUserAPI(request)
    console.log("GENERATED DATA FIXTURE TEST - " + testContext.user.firstName)
  })

  test('TEST 2', async ({testContext}) => {
    console.log("GENERATED DATA FIXTURE TEST - " + testContext.user.firstName)
  })

})

In TEST1 we generate some user and store it into our variable, in TEST2 we shouldn't see that value but wee see it. Shouldn't fixtures be created on beforeEach level of test ?

Running 2 tests using 1 worker
[Chromium] › tests/e2e/fixturetest.spec.ts:19:7 › Login Tests › TEST 1
initializeEnvironment()

[TEST STARTED] - TEST 1

generateAndRegisterUserAPI()
getNewUserData()
Generate First Name is -> Kübra
Generated Last Name is -> Doğan
Generated Username is -> lazytiger654
Generated Email is -> kubra.dogan@example.com
Generated Password is -> jYJWy
registerNewUser()
GENERATED DATA FIXTURE TEST - Kübra

[TEST FINISHED] - with status [passed]

[Chromium] › tests/e2e/fixturetest.spec.ts:24:7 › Login Tests › TEST 2

[TEST STARTED] - TEST 2

GENERATED DATA FIXTURE TEST - Kübra

[TEST FINISHED] - with status [passed]

  2 passed (4.0s)



No, each test should be self-contained and idempotent. Don't rely on ordering. If you want the data to be in each test, use beforeEach or beforeAll.

So fixtures should be no-go for our situation ?

Not unless you call them in your beforeEach, or repeatedly as the first line of each test case you want to use them in, which is probably not what you want.
